# move player object towards cursor direction in canvas (slither.io style)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've found similar questions but not exact. I can do this with mouse onclick but I'm not sure how to handle it with just 'mousemove' event.

my current situation [JSFiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/robstao/9zLsvw5p/1/)

I'm trying to make it so the screen is translated towards the mouse while moving my player, not only on mousemove. But I'm not sure how else to go about this.

I have a player object that updates when mouse is moved.

```
function Player (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,30,0,Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
    }

    this.update = function () {
        this.x = playerX;
        this.y = playerY;
        this.draw();
    }
}
```

this update function doesn't allow *contstant* movment, but when I try to implement something it ends up creating large amounts of lag - clearly I'm taking a wrong approach.

At the moment, I'm just detection where the mouse is in compared to the center of the screen.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    moveWorld(event);
});    

function moveWorld(e){
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    // playerSpeed is 3
    var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2
    var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2
    // move south
    if (y < centerY) {
        ctx.translate (0,playerSpeed);
        playerY -= playerSpeed;        
    }
    // move e
    if (x < centerX) {
        ctx.translate (playerSpeed,0);
        playerX -=playerSpeed;
    } 
    // move north
    if (y > centerY) {
        ctx.translate (0,-playerSpeed);
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    // move west
    if (x > centerX) {
        ctx.translate (-playerSpeed,0);
        playerX +=playerSpeed;
    }
    drawWorld();
}
```

and finally to render it all.

```
function drawWorld(){
    requestAnimationFrame(drawWorld); // refresh world

    //  CLEAR
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerHeight,innerHeight);

    // world
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(110, 30, 50, 50);

    // player
    player.update();

}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    moveWorld(event);
});    

drawWorld();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assume mouse is at center of screen
2. On mousemove, update the mouse coordinates
3. Run `moveWorld` in a loop using the last known mouse coordinates for directions.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var playerX = canvas.width / 2;
var playerY = canvas.height / 2;

$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $("#login,#game,#canvas").width( $(this).width());
    $("#login,#game,#canvas").height( $(this).height());
    playerX = canvas.width / 2;
    playerY = canvas.height / 2;
}).resize();

var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var playerSpeed = 3;

var mouseX = centerX;
var mouseY = centerY;

function mouseUpdate(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
}

function moveWorld(){
    var x = mouseX;
    var y = mouseY;
    var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2
    var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2
    // move south
    if (y < centerY) {
        ctx.translate (0,playerSpeed);
        playerY -= playerSpeed;        
    }
    // move e
    if (x < centerX) {
        ctx.translate (playerSpeed,0);
        playerX -=playerSpeed;
    } 
    // move north
    if (y > centerY) {
        ctx.translate (0,-playerSpeed);
        playerY += playerSpeed;
    }
    // move west
    if (x > centerX) {
        ctx.translate (-playerSpeed,0);
        playerX +=playerSpeed;
    }
    drawWorld();
    requestAnimationFrame(moveWorld);
}

var player = new Player (playerX, playerY);
var counter = 0;


function drawWorld() {
    //  CLEAR
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerHeight,innerHeight);
    
    // world
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(110, 30, 50, 50);

    // player
    player.update();

}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    mouseUpdate(event);
});    

requestAnimationFrame(moveWorld);

function Player (x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    
    this.draw = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,30,0,Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
    }

    this.update = function () {
        this.x = playerX;
        this.y = playerY;
        this.draw();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: using intervals is not the right way to do canvas animations. You should use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.

Comment: I noticed this also created large lag, which was part of my problem. I've attempted a similar solution that you suggested and alas - to no clean solution.

Comment: @Robolisk - you had a `requestAnimationFrame()` going at the start of `drawWorld` - after I removed that, the lag stopped for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

As you are trying to develop a Slither.io system, I assume that you are looking for [Slither.io Clone](https://loonride.com/examples/slither-io/slither-io/) made by [Loonride available on Github](https://github.com/Loonride/slither.io-clone)

---

Are you trying to achieve something like the following ? [Phaser 3 : pointer - move event](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cinput%5Cpointer%5Cmove%20event.js)

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var player = null;

function preload ()
{
    this.load.spritesheet('balls', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/balls.png', { frameWidth: 17, frameHeight: 17 });
}

function create ()
{
 player = this.add.image(0,0, 'balls', Phaser.Math.Between(0, 5));

    this.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {

        player.x = pointer.x;
        player.y = pointer.y;

    }, this);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="phaser-example" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Not entirely, I'm trying to do something more relevant to how slither.io is, where the player (character) sits in the middle of the screen and moves the along the map.

Comment: I updated the code snippet above according to the required characteristics

Comment: but you see, the object follows the mouse, instead of staying in the center of the screen where the viewing angle changes instead. I have a JS fiddle exmaple in my question that shows similiar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this kind of thing is to let the browser handle the 'frame tick' by using [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r5e2ht1v/4/

```
var mouseX, mouseY; 

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    mouseX = event.clientX; 
  mouseY = event.clientY; 
});    

function drawWorld(){

    //  CLEAR
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerHeight,innerHeight);

    // world
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(110, 30, 50, 50);

    // player
    player.update();
    moveWorld(); 

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawWorld);

}

window.requestAnimationFrame(drawWorld);
```

There are some more performance optimisations you can use here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas